# Error "Extended mathchar used as mathchar" when using \bm

Tags: xetex, miktex, unicode-math, bm

In an equation I want to use some bold calligraphic letters. This should be possible using `\bm{\mathcal{X}}`. However, even wenn using `\bm{X}` alone I get an error ("Extended mathchar used as mathchar").
I use xelatex from the latest MikTeX distribution.

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{XITS}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
This is a simple math example with a variable $k$.
This does not work $\bm{k}$.
What I actually need is this: $\bm{\mathcal{X}}$ and $\bm{\Theta}$.
\end{document}
```

Do I do something wrong or is there a bug in XeLaTeX or in one of the packages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `unicode-math` you don't generally need `bm`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{XITS}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\begin{document}

This is a simple math example with a variable $k$.
This works $\symbfit{k}$.
What I actually need is this: $\mathbfcal{X}$ and $\symbf{\Theta}$.
Compare with $\mathcal{X}$ and $\Theta$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's cool! Although now I have to change all occurences of \bm in my old code...